# Point Grey firefly MV, dc1394, and USB 3.0

Tags: c, usb, computer-vision, libdc1394, firefly-mv

I am trying to grab frames from a point grey firefly mv, and I have written an interface for my program using dc1394 driver. The driver works fine when I the firefly is connected to a USB 2.0 port, but when I connect to a USB 3.0 port, dc1394 throws the following error on the function call dc1394_capture_setup()

```
libdc1394 error: usb: Failed to submit initial transfer 13
```

The error code is not listed in dc1394/log.h, and identical settings work in a USB 2.0 port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the problem can be solved with by updating to firmware version 1.6, and updating the linux kernel. It doesn't work at 3.5, it does work at 3.11. I'm not sure about in between.